# How to define or support a code language on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I just got Visual Studio, and every time I try running the code, a message pops up and says "code language not supported or defined. This happens with any language I try to use. How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Which languages did you try? Did you try to repair restart Visual Studio in the Visual Studio Installer? Did you restart all instances of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 11):

In the bottom right corner of the window notice where it says "plain text", Click this and you should see all the available language options. It's probably set to autodetect right now.

Comment: this is useful ,it works

Answer (score 7):

STEPS to follow:

**1)** Install the `"CODE RUNNER" extension` in Visual Studio (VS) (if you have not done so, yet).

**2)** After that, go to VS "`Settings`" (by clicking the wheel) and, in the search field on the top, enter: "`run code`".

**3)** You'll see, to the right, all the options available for "Code Runner" settings. Scroll down, and you'll see a field that says,

> Code-runner: Executor Map By File Extension.

**Set the executor of each file extension.**

**4)** Click on:   "`Edit in Settings.json`".

**5)** Then, scroll down until you see  "`code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension`" field brackets. You'll be able to see all the files extensions (e.g., ".vb", ".scala", etc.) and the corresponding executor application that run such files after the colons, to the right.

**6)** If you don't see the extension for the file you're trying to run (e.g., ".js"), just enter it following the same (json) format as the ones above, with the executor program (that you need to know) that runs it, to the right.

**EXAMPLE:** in the Mac, for a javascript (JS) file with extension ".js" (assuming you've already installed NODE, the JS executor app), you should enter a line at the end (inside the last bracket) such as,

> ".js": "node"

(**NOTE:** make sure you put a coma (,) at the end of the previous line, right before your addition)

**7)** SAVE your edit, and run your program by clicking the arrow on the top right corner of Visual Studio window. Your program output will be shown on the OUTPUT tab in the section below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:
Close your folder from the Explorer and reopen and run your file. It solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

You saw that error message in vscode because you probably used the shortcut Alt+Ctrl+N to run the code while the output terminal is selected instead of the script. try click the mouse in the script area and do it again, it should work. if the run the code by pressing the button on the top right corner and you still see the same error msg that means you need to check .Jason settings.

Answer (score 0):

Read the language support page for MS Visual Studio: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview

You can define a languages in the files.associations setting.

If you haven't setup language support: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
In the right bottom of the window notice where it says "plain text", Click this and you should see all the available options. It probably provides the available list of language .

Option 2: Uninstall  the current version and install stable version of visual studio code

On my case, I follow first option at first but I could able to solve the problem so I uninstall the visual studio code and solving the problem using stable version. Try once I may work on your case

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run an HTML file in VS Code, the main problem is that VS Code no longer supports the `code runner` extension for the `HTML` format. So instead of running it from code runner, you can directly run it from the browser.

Here are some options on how to do it:

1. Save the HTML file with the proper extension, i.e `file.html`.
   Go to the folder where you stored the file.
   Open it directly if its default application is a browser, or right-click on the file and select `open with` and then your browser.
2. Download the extension `LivePreview` in VS Code.
   From there, you can get your preview by right-clicking the file in VS Code.
   There might also be an option in the top right corner when opening the file.