# Running SQL queries in VSCode

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code

I installed Postgresql extension in VSCode Editor. When I try to run SQL queries, it says "Language code not supported or defined". How to fix this problem?[image]

Comment: no it says, "Code language not supported or defined". g00gling that found this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47913048/1132334

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, the code runner extension is trying to run the query, which does't support SQL queries. Try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to run the query (As available in [mssql](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-mssql.mssql) extension), or use [pgsql](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=doublefint.pgsql) extension, which is fixed clone of postgresql extension.