# The "Code language not supported or defined." message for HTML in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, settings

My Visual Studio Code is not working.
Everytime I run a HTML code, it displays "Code language not supported or defined."

[VS Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C0bg.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your image you sent since there is only one I am only speculating. Here a re a few things

1. The bottom right corner of your screen it says "CSS" check to make sure it is not on autodetect and you can also see all available languages you can use.
2. I also noticed on your screen it doesn't seem like you have saved the file try saving the file in the appropriate format in this case html.
3. If these don't work please see references to get an idea where to start. A similar question on Stack Overflow has been asked. Thank you and hope this can help.

References

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913048/how-to-define-or-support-a-code-language-on-visual-studio

-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BN_CORsgDbU

-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7tXN9PtO9A

-https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43394